# Testing a saved Convolutional autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, anomaly-detection

I have trained and saved a Convolutional Autoencoder in Keras. Before saving the model in .h5 format, it had a training loss of 0.2394 and a validation loss of 0.2586. In testing the saved model, I get a loss which is more than double the validation loss, 0.6707. I am actually testing it with the sample from the training data just to see if I will get the same loss or even closer as it was during training.

Here is how I calculate the loss, where 'total' is the total number of images I am passing to test the model

```
score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(predicteds,images))
print ('Loss:',score/total)
```

Am I making a mistake on how I calculate the test loss?

Here is model compile

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

and train verbose

> Epoch 18/20 167/167 [==============================] - 
>   462s 3s/step - loss: 0.2392 - val_loss: 0.2585
>
> Epoch 19/20 167/167 [==============================] - 
>   461s 3s/step -  loss: 0.2399 - val_loss: 0.2609
>
> Epoch 20/20 167/167 [==============================] - 
>   475s 3s/step - loss: 0.2394 - val_loss: 0.2586

Comment: Can you share some of the code (model compile) and training results (verbose)? It will help to understand the loss and metrics used by the model.

Comment: Sure @skillsmuggler, I have added the compile codes and verbose on the post, please see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the metrics and the loss function.

Based on your `model.compile()`, you are using the `binary_crossentropy` loss function. This means that the loss mentioned in the verbose is related to the binary crossentropy (both `loss` - training loss and `val_loss` - validation loss).

You are scoring the model using RMSE, but then comparing the RMSE to binary crossentropy loss.

To train using MSE or to make use of other comparable metrics, you need to compile the model with the MSE loss or make use of MSE as a metric. For more information on [`keras.losses`](https://keras.io/losses/) and [`keras.metrics`](https://keras.io/metrics/), have a look at the documentation.

Comment: I have already tried to compile with  `autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')` but still I get the same results.

Comment: this one worked, I also came to realize my training and validation images were normalized but not my test set. After normalizing it also, the loss has fallen to an acceptable value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you complied with `autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')`. But it seens that you use **root mean square error** in `np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(predicteds,images))` to calculate the loss rather than mean square error. When a number is less than 1, its square root is larger than itself. Maybe this is why your test loss is strangely larger than you training loss. By the way, you can use `autoencoder.evaluate(images, images)` to get the test loss.

Comment: with `autoencoder.evaluate(images,images)` I get a loss of `2517.8763163798562`